# Inline assembly in C. Wrong translation

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, i386

I have this function in C:

```
int write(int fd, char *buffer, int size)
{
    int ret;

    __asm__("mov $4, %%eax;"
            "mov %0, %%ebx;"
            "mov %1, %%ecx;"
            "mov %2, %%edx;"
            "int $0x80"
            : "=r"(ret)
            : "g"(fd), "g"(buffer), "g"(size)
            : "eax", "ebx", "ecx", "edx");

    if (ret < 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Which translates to this code in ASM:

```
push   %ebp
mov    %esp,%ebp
push   %esi
push   %ebx
mov    $0x4,%eax
mov    %esi,%ebx
mov    0x8(%ebp),%ecx
mov    0xc(%ebp),%edx
int    $0x80
mov    %esi,%eax
sar    $0x1f,%eax
pop    %ebx
pop    %esi
pop    %ebp
ret
```

As fd, *buffer and size are function parameters, they are in 0x8(%ebp), 0xc(%ebp) and 0x10(%ebp), respectively. Why does GCC identify the position of fd in %esi, and the other two variables shifted in the stack? How can I get this function to run (get the variables in the registers properly)?

Comment: Why don't you use [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)? It is more portable, and might even be faster because of [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html)

Comment: As I comment below, I'm writing my own OS as part of a university subject. Obviously, while using Linux I will use write.

Comment: Note that int (interrupt) routines do not have a return value, so this code sequence will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the calling convention on your architecture. If you want to constrain the other parameters to registers you should use the register constraints directly: eg. `"a"` stands for the `eax` register.

Also the `$4` at the beginning looks wrong to me.

Something along the line

```
     __asm__(
        "int $0x80"
        : "=b"(ret)
        : "c"(fd), "d"(buffer), "a"(size)
        );
```

should do, if these are really the registers that your syscall uses.

But, in the whole I think you shouldn't do this yourself. Your OS certainly has something like `syscall` that provides that functionality to you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I misunderstood the concept of constraints. They are not "where is expected to be" but "where do I want them to be (if possible to put it there)". So now it works as expected. And in this case I cannot call the OS, because I'm writing the OS (university practice).

Answer (score 0):

Arguments to inline assembler are numbered from zero starting with the outputs, so %0 is ret, %1 is fd, %2 is buffer and %3 is size.